# Redirect to path if no results found Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling, elasticsearch, searchkick

Using elasticsearch with searchkick on rails 4 app.

Trying to redirect to a certain path if no search results found. I recently switched from solr and sunspot over to elasticsearch so still getting familiar with elastic.

I tried using my old code (from sunspot):

```
def index
  if params[:query].present?
    @articles = Article.search(params[:query], misspellings: {edit_distance: 1})
  else
    @articles = Article.all
  end

   if @articles.results.any?
     @results = @articles.results
   else
     return redirect_to request_path
   end
end
```

The redirecting works when no results found, but if you click the search(submit) button with no query in the search bar it returns an error:

```
undefined method `results' for #<Article::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000102300d10>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know it's something simple, but I can't seem to find an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
if @articles.blank?
  redirect_to request_path
else
  @results = @articles.results
end
```

Comment: Uday, I saw that you were struggling with code formatting, I have done it for you. :), however the proposed solution seems still fail when `params[:query].present?` will be `false`, which was the original problem @Kathan.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if @articles.respond_to?(:results) # if we got results from ElasticSearch
   @results = @articles.results
elsif @articles.present? # if user has entered blank string ('@articles = Article.all' case)
   @results = @articles
else
   return redirect_to request_path
end
```

Comment: .result still throwing an error. Got it to work with @articles.blank? Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Check my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555227/redirect-to-path-if-no-results-found-elasticsearch#comment47261909_29555297